# Change of spotlight bulbs

Tags: lighting, bulb

I am trying to figure out how to change the spotlight bulbs shown in the image below. The normal push and twist approach I use with other spotlight types doesn't work. Didn't manage to find anything online.

[image]

Comment: Outer rim should pop out with a small screw driver, don't try to remove the bulb like a twist and push one. it wont come out like that

Comment: Amazing, it is exactly the same as the extractor fan light! I used a small screwdriver to remove the outer part. Form it as an answer below and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very common type of under cabinet spotlight, unfortunately it comes with both LED and Halogen types and in some cases its not easy to see what lies behind the colored or forested covers.

For the halogen type bulbs good auld push and twist should do the job releasing the old bulb so if this is not working for you don't try too hard its probably not a halogen light bulb.

For the LED fittings there is usually an outer rim which can be popped out with a small flat head screw driver. These fittings can easily be scratched so be gentle while trying to pop the rim, small piece of electrical tape on the tip of the screw driver would do miracles not scratching metal or plastic fittings like this!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an led spotlight I have. If the globe is plastic it's led. Because they are flush it's hard to get a good twist on them. I would try wearing a plastic glove for "grip" and twist it out. Worst case the base stays and you have to use pliers to remove the base.